# Pasar Datos a una ventana modal con jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

tengo una funcion JS, que recibe un parametro.
Esta funcion, levanta un cuadro de dialogomodal con jqueri.UI
y necesito saber como pasarle el parametro, ya que este cuadro de dialogo, le permite al usuario seleccionar un archivo, y cuando se selecciona debo pasarle al controller (action Result) el parametro original (idProceso) mas el archivo seleccionado...

este es el codigo que tengo hasta elmomento

Aca el div que contiene el modal

```
<div id="ModalCargaInfoAistencia" class="display">
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Proceso", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>
                <h2>Seccion Archivo de carga</h2>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>
                <input type="File" name="file" id="file" value="Selecciona el archivo" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Subir archivo" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
    <script>
    function CargarExcel(ProcesoId) {
        $("#ModalCargaInfoAistencia").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Cargar Informacion Asistencia",
            width: 800,
            height: 500,
            resizable: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 400
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 400
            },
            buttons: {
                "Cancelar": function () { $("#ModalCargaInfoAistencia").dialog("close"); }
            }
        });
    };
</script>  @*Modal Selecciona Excel Asistencia*@
```

en el siguiente ActionResult recibo sin problemas el archivo... pero necesito obtener el ProcesoId que recibe la funcion JS

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string ??? como le paso el parametro aca??)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            ... hace cosas con el archivo..

        }

        // Tu podras decidir que hacer aqui
        // si el archivo es nulo
        return RedirectToAction("Inicio");

    }
```

Comment: dentro de tu Html.BeginForm pon un input  de tipo hidden con el nombre del parametro que recibes (ProcesoId) y cuando lances la funcion CargarExcel le  agregas el valor  al input con $("#ProcesoId"),val(ProcesoId);

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda...  mira, puse el siguiente input                     <input type="hidden" id="ProcId" />
 y en el JS lo asigne de la siguiente manera:   $("#ProcId").val(ProcesoId);  (valide que el dato ProcesoId si existe), pero en el ActionResult, el parametro me llega null (lo defini como string).

Comment: es que tiene que ser name="ProcId"  y asi tal cual lo recibes en tu metodo en el controlador algo como  <input type="hidden"  id="ProcId" name ="ProcId">

Comment: y en el controlador public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string  ProcId) o si es un entero pues en lugar de string ProcId pues es int ProcId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de tu `form` en el modal pon un `input` tipo `hidden` para que ahí puedas recibir el parámetro y mandarlo al controlador

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Proceso", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="hidden"  name="ProcesoId" id="ProcesoId">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>
                    <h2>Seccion Archivo de carga</h2>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>
                    <input type="File" name="file" id="file" value="Selecciona el archivo" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Subir archivo" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

No se que acción dispare tu función pero ahí dentro puedes asignar el valor a el `input` para mandarlo al controlador algo así:

```
   <script>
    function CargarExcel(ProcesoId) {
        $("#ProcesoId").val(ProcesoId);
        $("#ModalCargaInfoAistencia").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Cargar Informacion Asistencia",
            width: 800,
            height: 500,
            resizable: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 400
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 400
            },
            buttons: {
                "Cancelar": function () { $("#ModalCargaInfoAistencia").dialog("close"); }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Por ultimo para recibir el parametro en tu metodo dentro del controlador seria algo asi:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string ProcesoId)
{
}
```

Nota: el tipo de parametro depende del tipo que sea el valor que mandas(string ProcesoId, intProcesoId)

Comment: Excelente maestro.. funciono muy bien. muchas gracias por tu ayuda